# How to change Konsole title in bash?

Tags: bash, konsole, window-title

I would like to have the Konsole title changed every time I run a loop, like this:

```
while read line; do
  echo $line $i/$numline
  echo -ne "\033]0;$line $i/$numline\007"
  commands
  let i=i+1
done<text
```

I've found that the `echo -ne "\033]0;text\007"`command doesn't work.

Comment: the escape sequence looks fine. it should set you title correctly. maybe your prompt configuration resets your title afterwards. try `echo -ne "\033]0;foo\007";sleep 3` this should change you title and after three secondsyour prompt should set it back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to first go to settings of `konsole`:

settings -> configure current profile -> Tabs -> Tab title format = %w

The konsole by default ignores what is asked for, it does its own thing, as configured. `%w` tells is replaced by what ever the shell wants it to be. There are other codes, use the insert button it knows all the codes.

---

A brief note on getting the shell to take over from what the terminal emulator was doing.

I have this is my `~/.bashrc` it updates the title. You may have to do more research into bash variable `PS1`, or look at variable `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

```
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: This works. However I would like to have the old title whenever I don't run any scripts. Is it possible to manually change the tab title format in command? Thank you.

Comment: Yes I added a brief note, but it is a separate question. So just something to help you get started.